# What is wrong with this if/else Javascript function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, socket.io

```
$('.chatterbox_comment_form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var file        = $('#chatterbox_comment_file_upload_1')[0].files[0];
    var reader      = new FileReader();
    var white_space = /^\s+$/;
    var file_val    = $('#chatterbox_comment_file_upload_1').val();
    var exts        = ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'bmp', 'gif', 'svg'];
    var comment_textarea = $('.form_comment_input');

    if(!file) {

        if(comment_textarea.val() == '' || white_space.test(comment_textarea.val())) {  
            $('.chatterbox_comment_error').html("Can't be blank");
            comment_textarea.css('border', '1px solid #b20000');
        }
        else {
            socket.emit('chatterbox comment', comment_textarea.val(), user.name);
            $('.chatterbox_comment_error').html("");
            comment_textarea.css('border', '1px solid #ccc');
        }
    }
    else if(file)
    {

        var get_ext = file_val.split('.');

        get_ext = get_ext.reverse();

        if(!$.inArray(get_ext[0], exts) > -1) 
        {
            $('.chatterbox_comment_error').html('Only .jpg .png .bmp .gif .svg files are allowed');
        } 
        else 
        {
            // file_val exists and the extension is valid.
            reader.onload  = function(evt) {
                socket.emit('chatterbox comment', $('.form_comment_input').val(), user.name, evt.target.result);
            };

            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            $('.chatterbox_comment_error').html("");
            comment_textarea.css('border', '1px solid #ccc');
        }

    } 

        $('#chatterbox_comment_file_upload_1').val('');
});
```

What I am trying to do is on submit of this textarea, check if there are either only blank input and check to see if the file uploaded is valid (png jpg bmp or svg), if it is not, then display the error message. If it is valid, then send it to the node server. This function is somewhat working. It validates the completely blank input, but when trying to send an image it doesnt send it and it doesnt validate incorrect file uploads such as .pdf for example. I believe my if/else statements are somehow incorrectly written. Any suggestions? cheers

Here is the server.js with the function handling the socket.emit call

```
socket.on('chatterbox comment', function(data, username, image){
    console.log(data, username, image);
    // io.sockets.in(socket.room).emit('chatterbox comment', data, username, image);
});
```

Comment: What is the value of `comment_textarea` ? Is it an undeclared variable?

Comment: Check your variables in your if else. Are you testing variables with non-boolean values? You should use a `==` or `===` in those cases. I also see this one `!$.inArray(get_ext[0], exts) > -1` which must be `!($.inArray(get_ext[0], exts) > -1)` . Cheers kaPinoy.

Comment: 'comment_textarea = $('.form_comment_input');' Sorry, forgot to include that in

Comment: Please update your code as you make changes.

Comment: You might want to look into the `accept` attribute for your `input` tag.  Check out http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_accept.asp to perhaps make it easier to filter for image files.

Comment: @itsmikem Please stop promoting the site; even if it is 'better' than the absolute train-wreck it was, there are many better resources available.

Comment: As a side issue, I don't see you normalizing the case of the file extensions. So, for example `MyPicture.Jpeg` would be rejected because `.Jpeg` (initial uppercase) does not match `.jpeg`

Comment: @user2864740 I will abide by your request.  I didn't realize w3schools had a poor reputation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have an else ***after*** checking for file_val. I think you want to do it after checking for invalid extensions.

How about this?

```
   $('.chatterbox_comment_form').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    var file        = $('#chatterbox_comment_file_upload_1')[0].files[0];
    var reader      = new FileReader();
    var white_space = /^\s+$/;
    var file_val    = $('#chatterbox_comment_file_upload_1').val();
    var exts        = ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'bmp', 'gif', 'svg'];

    if(!file_val) {
        // No file, 
        if(comment_textarea.val() == '' || white_space.test(comment_textarea.val())) {  
            $('.chatterbox_comment_error').html("Can't be blank");
            comment_textarea.css('border', '1px solid #b20000');
        }
        else {
            socket.emit('chatterbox comment', comment_textarea.val(), user.name);
            $('.chatterbox_comment_error').html("");
            comment_textarea.css('border', '1px solid #ccc');
        }
    }
    else {
        // If we have a file...

        var get_ext = file_val.split('.');

        get_ext = get_ext.reverse();

        // Fixes conditional issue
        if ($.inArray(get_ext[0], exts) == -1) {
            $('.chatterbox_comment_error').html('Only .jpg .png .bmp .gif .svg files are allowed');
        } else {
            // file_val exists and the extension is valid.
            reader.onload  = function(evt) {
                socket.emit('chatterbox comment', comment_textarea.val(), user.name, evt.target.result);
                console.log("reader.onload() - calling socket.emit()");
                console.log(comment_textarea.val(), user.name, evt.target.result);

                $('#chatterbox_comment_file_upload_1').val('');
            };

            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            $('.chatterbox_comment_error').html("");
            comment_textarea.css('border', '1px solid #ccc');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Mr. Hinson, your code seems to be working, it validates the image but it doesnt send it through to the node server.

Comment: Would you be so kind as to post the node snippet that handles the socket.emit('chatterbox comment') call? Also, is user.name defined?

Comment: Of course, please see the edited version of this post. And yes, user.name is part of an object that grabs the currently authenticated user's name. This script is being run on a blade file which allows me to grab the name fairly easily

Comment: also, I made a mistake on the original post, I should have said that if there is no file, validate the textbox, if there is a file, the textbox doesn't need validation. and if the textbox and file are not blank, go through to the node server. Everything seems to be working except the validation on the file. I believe the extensions array is wrong somehow

Comment: Hi Arvin, I've updated my answer to fit your conditions (I think). I'm not sure why the data isn't being received by the server, but have added a console.log so you can check if reader.onload is ever called.

Comment: Regarding the extension array - it looks good to me. In your question, you used `if(!$.inArray(get_ext[0], exts) > -1)`, but you probably meant `if(!($.inArray(get_ext[0], exts) > -1))`. I shortened this to `if ($.inArray(get_ext[0], exts) == -1)`